# Selenium Visible, Non Visible Elements (Drop Down)

Tags: python, selenium, visible, mousemove, invisible

I am trying to select all elements of a dropdown.

The site I am testing on is: http://jenner.com/people

The dropdown(checkbox list) I am trying to access is the "locations" list.

I am using Python.  I am getting the following error: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with'

The code I am using is:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    url = "http://jenner.com/people"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)
    page = driver.page_source

    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='filter offices']")
    elements = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("input")

    counter = 0
    while counter <= len(elements) -1:
            driver.get(url)
            element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='filter offices']")
            elements1 = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("input")
            elements1[counter].click()
            counter = counter + 1
```

I have tried a few variations, including clicking the initial element before clicking on the dropdown options, that didnt work.  Any ideas on how to make elements visible in Selenium.  I have spent the last few hours searching for an answer online.  I have seen a few posts regarding moving the mouse in Selenium, but havent found a solution that works for me yet.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: figure out the python code buddy as I doesn't know about it.Let me know does it work for you.

Comment: I will.  Thanks Omkar.  I worked on it a bit this morning after you posted, and will get back to it later today.  Have some things to do today before I can get back to work.

Comment: Omkar.  Your solution isn't working for me.  I have converted it to Python.  I think there are two issues.  First, I have same issue I had before.  Second, I am not getting this coversion from filter offices to filter offices open.

Comment: After click on "location" the class name changes from 'filter offices' to 'filter offices open' that dynamic class name.

Answer (score 2):

As input check-boxes are not visible at initial state,they get visible after click on "filter offices" option.Also there is change in class name changes from "filter offices" to "filter offices open",if you have observed in firebug.Below code works for me but it is in Java.But you can figure out python as it contain really basic code.

```
    driver.get("http://jenner.com/people");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='filter offices']/div")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000L);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='filter offices open']"));
    Thread.sleep(2000L);
    List <WebElement> elements =  element.findElements(By.tagName("input"));

    for(int i=0;i<=elements.size()-1;i++)
    {       
        elements.get(i).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
        elements =  element.findElements(By.tagName("input"));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it when looking for other information. I don't know if you were doing QA on the site to see if the proper cities were showing in the drop down, or if you were actually interacting with the site to get the list of people who should be at each location.  (Side note: selecting a location then un-selecting it returns 0 results if you don't reset the filter - possibly not desired behavior.)

If you were trying to get a list of users at each location on this site, I would think it easier to not use Selenium. Here is a pretty simple solution to pull the people from the first city "Chicago."  Of course, you could make a list of the cities that you are supposed to look for and sub them into the "data" variable by looping through the list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://jenner.com/people/search'
data = 'utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=%2BayQ8%2FyDPAtNNlHRn15Fi9w9OgXS12eNe8RZ8saTLmU%3D&search_scope=full_name' \
       '&search%5Bfull_name%5D=&search%5Boffices%5D%5B%5D=Chicago'
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
people_results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'name'})
for p in people_results:
    print p.text
```